# Link CSS file with HTML file in Unity Power UI

Tags: html, css

I want to link css file with html in Unity with the help of Power UI. I already converted css file into bytes format but it not still worked. Here is the code

```
<head>
    <link href="Resources/bootstrapUnity.css.bytes"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Game</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Play</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Test</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you looked into Resources Protocol? https://powerui.kulestar.com/wiki/index.php?title=Resources_Protocol 

Also a heads up: https://powerui.kulestar.com/2018/02/17/asset-store-package-depreciated/

Answer (score 1):

The default href with PowerUI is `resources://` so you don't need `Resources/` just `/bootstrapUnity.css`.

(If you have the .bytes extension added, this means you don't need it mentioned in the HTML file, as Unity will 'name' it without .bytes so that .css/.js links work normally..)..

Assuming `bootstrapUnity.css.bytes` is in the root of a 'resources' folder, try:
`<link href="/bootstrapUnity.css"/>`